# TWIG: Translation of string with variables?

Tags: symfony, twig

In my translation.yml I have this var:

```
all.in.EN: All In Great Britain
```

In my Twig I have something like this:

```
{% trans %}all.in.{{ countryKey }}{% endtrans %}
```

This doesn't work so I tried to put this in a variable:

```
{% set allInName = 'all.in.{{ countryKey }}' %}
{% trans %}allInName{% endtrans %}
```

But then the output is `allInName` and not the translation. Someone an idea what I'm doing wrong?
THNAKS!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to do it like this :

```
{{ ('all.in.'~countryKey)|trans }}
```

already tested this works. the '~' sign is to concatenate, and |trans filter translate

Comment: THANK YOU, exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{% set allInName = 'all.in.' ~ countryKey %}
{{allInName | trans}}
```

Comment: beat you to it in 3min :p and btw no need for setting a variable